# PHP overide parent return type in child method

Tags: php

When I create an abstract BaseClass in PHP and declare return types on the implemented methods I can override the return type as in the example below, the same goes for properties with types. **Is this intended and expected behaviour?** Note: all this is done with php 7.4.

```
// BaseRepository.php

abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected object $model;

    public function getAll() : object
    {
        return $this->model->get();
    }
}

// UserRepository.php

class UserRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    protected User $model;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->model = $user;
    }

    public function getAll() : User
    {
        return parent::getAll();
    }
}
```

From my observations, I conclude that you can override the return type of the parent class in the child class if the new return type is of the same type as declared on the parent class. In this example, `User` is an object and the return type of the parent function is `object`. If I change the return type of the child function to `string` an error gets thrown.

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Users\Repositories\UserRepository::getAll(Illuminate\Http\Request
>   $request): string must be compatible with
>   Base\BaseRepository::getAll(Illuminate\Http\Request
>   $request): object in
>   /home/.../user-module/src/Repositories/UserRepository.php
>   on line 30

In the PHP documentation I cannot find any relevant information besides this line:

> When overriding a parent method, the child's method must match any
>   return type declaration on the parent. If the parent doesn't define a
>   return type, then the child method may do so.

Comment: Your noted observation seems to exactly match the noted documentation.  So I'm a little confused as to what the question is.

Comment: *"If I change the return type of the child function to string an error gets thrown."* -- because it breaks the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: _Is this intended and expected behaviour?_ Yes, by your own description in the question you confirm this. Perhaps you are trying to achieve something else you have yet to state?

Comment: This should work ok in PHP 7.4, thanks to the [*Covariant Returns and Contravariant Parameters*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters) changes. See https://3v4l.org/Z9K3j . Before that, you're out of luck.

Comment: PHP7.4 will support this.

Comment: @Martin No, that was my exact question. I only found out because I was implementing return types in an application and was on the lookout for generic types to use in the `BaseRepository`, which is impossible atm. Then I tried this and it worked to my surprise. Only wanted to know if this was expected in PHP and why it was not really documented in the manual or couldn't find any blog posts about this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the documentation just hasn't been updated to match the behaviour change in PHP 7.4 - this has only recently become supported

Comment: @iainn Thanks for the links, why did I not found these?

Comment: Did [this comment/flag as a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method/59614744#comment105392435_59614629) answer the question? Or should that flag be retracted?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That was a totally different question, had nothing to do with my question. That question as about the difference between a string (String) and an object, my question was about changing return types in PHP when using class inheritance.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close other than the duplicate, yet that's what it shows as being closed for. I find that a bit odd.

Comment: @Odyssee That is really odd that I didn't get the notification ping [for this comment to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method?noredirect=1#comment105393112_59614629), I might post on meta about it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  If 3 the close votes are all for different reasons, it seems that the logic selects the first-voted reason as the one to display.  That's what I've noted so far, anyway.  With only 3 votes required now, it is more likely that all the votes will be for different reasons than when 5 were required.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That's strange indeed. I don't mind if the question got closed, I got what I needed thanks to iaini's comment, but the reason is not a valid reason. The proposed question that should solve my question dates back from 2013 and is irrelevant, what I describeb was not possible with PHP until the release of php 7.4 in December 2019.

Comment: @Odyssee Very. I guess that duplicate flags get precedence. Oh well. Still odd though that [your previous ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method#comment105393112_59614629) to me still isn't showing up in my "recent messages". [I posted on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392686/1415724) but not getting good reviews for it.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ok. Well I voted as unclear. See the above comment to the OP please, about "pings".